# QT on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi4

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4 and I am using Ubuntu 20.04 running in VirtualBox on a Windows 10 machine.

I have been following the steps presented in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmtN3Rmx9Rk&list=PLXAxzIhirYJGp1dMN0SxMRNCumubmpzWj&index=2&t=1686s. The goal is to run QT C++ applications on the Raspberry Pi

@24.20, the presenter issues the command:

`rsync -avz  --rsync-path="sudo rsync" pi@192.168.1.237:/lib sysroot`

His host machine receives a number of files. On the video I can see the contents of `lib/firmware`, `lib/modules.bak`, `lib/modules`, `lib/udev`

However, when I issue the same command, I only receive a symbolic link

```
receiving incremental file list
lib -> usr/lib
```

BTW, a symbolic link is also what I see on the RPi

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 May  7  2021 bin -> usr/bin
```

I tried adding the option `--copy-links`. It allows me to copy the files, but the `usr/bin` directory is about 3GB and it seems to have a many more folders (for instance `chromium-browser`) when compared to what I saw in the  video

Why the discrepancy? Did I miss an initial setup step, maybe? Any advice?

Comment: It seems you're trying to setup a cross-compilation toolchain. But if your goal is just to run Qt apps on the Pi, you can simply compile them on the Pi itself. Just install `qt5-default` and `build-essential` (and maybe `cmake`) there, and it should give you the build environment.

Comment: Ruslan, that is correct. I have a Raspberry Pi application with a 7" LCD. It would be a lot easier to set up cross-compilation. We did something similar for a beaglebone board, and  the expectation is that it should be possible to achieve the same -- the funny things is that all the references and the videos I found use the same step referenced in my post -- and there is never a problem -- so I am stomped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem.
the /lib you want to copy is a link, not a folder. It's linked to /usr/lib. So try it with

```
rsync -avz  --rsync-path="sudo rsync" pi@192.168.1.237:/usr/lib sysroot
```

Comment: thank you for your reply and apologies for the late reply